# Highchart advance formatting of x-Axis datetime labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jasper-reports

I have requirement to extend date label formatting to show time period beside date when value is measured.

You can see on image how it should look.

[image]

Any way to achieve this by using format function of Highchart API?

EDIT: I need implementation without using third party solutions, since I need to embed solution into jasper report.

Thanks

Comment: To group labels I think you should use this [plugin](https://www.highcharts.com/products/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories)

Comment: Your link looks like solution, but I did not want to pollute question with jasper reporting tag, as I need this implementation be pure javascript in highchart library, so I can embed it  inside report easily. Cannot use third part libraries.

Comment: Its an Highcharts plugin you can use it like all others modules made for Highcharts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to use 'grouped categories' plugin, you can create additional xAxis labels by Highcharts. SVGRenderer.

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var chart = this,
                ticks = chart.xAxis[0].ticks,
                xy;

            Highcharts.objectEach(ticks, function(tick) {
                if ((tick.pos + 2) % 3 === 0) {
                    xy = tick.label.xy;

                    chart.renderer.text('date', xy.x, xy.y + 20)
                        .attr({
                            'align': 'center'
                        })
                        .add();
                }
            });
        }
    }
},
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f7c54zop/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text